# Derived classes and smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, smart-pointers

```
class Object { /* */ };
```

and a few derived:

```
class Derived1 : public Object { /* */ };
class Derived2 : public Object { /* */ };
```

And I have a function which makes derived objects and returns pointer for `Object`;

```
Object *make()
{
   return new Derived1();
}
```

So, this way I have to wrap returned object by smart pointer, but what return type to use?

```
TYPE? make()
{
   return boost::shared_ptr<Derived1>(new Derived1());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Object> make()
{
return boost::shared_ptr<Object>(new Derived1());
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should probably return a pointer to the base class, not the derived class.

Comment: @John Dibling: If you can return a pointer to the derived class, why wouldn't you? What's the disadvantage? Obviously if you can't, then you can't.

Comment: @Charles:  Clearly I don't know enough about OP's problem to answer definitively.  I probably shouldn't have even commented.  But you are right in that "if you can't, then you can't."  But it is my general experience when dealing with polymorphic instantiations of abstract interfaces (which I assume OP is doing, possibly wrongly) that "you can't" more often than "you can" because of the code that uses these pointers, and so I default to returning the base pointer in these cases.

Answer (score 4):

Logically, the natural transformation would be to `boost::shared_ptr<Object>` but if the function *always* returns a `Derived1` then it would be better to return `boost::shared_ptr<Derived1>` so that clients can take advantage of the better static type information if they want to.

Why was it necessary for the original function to throw away static type information?

Comment: maybe it is a factory and it can return any type.

Comment: @bcsanches: By definition it is a factory function but there's still no reason to throw away more static type information than is strictly necessary.

Comment: +1 I realize that both this and the accepted answer is correct.  Who said programming is easy?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is easy:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Object> make()
{
   return boost::shared_ptr<Derived1>(new Derived1());
}
```

as the smart pointer preserve the pointer property wrt type conversion.